# OAuth2 and UWP Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, uwp, xamarin.forms

Can any one help me with this problem?

I don`t know how to use OAuth2 with UWP.

For example, on Andriod code of authentication looks like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPageRenderer))]

namespace TestTask.Droid
{
    class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private static bool _isShown;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (_isShown) return;
            _isShown = true;

            var activity = this.Context as Activity;

            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "someId",
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html"));

            auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    AuthInfo.Token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                    AuthInfo.UserID = eventArgs.Account.Properties["user_id"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    // The user cancelled
                }
            };

            activity?.StartActivity((Intent)auth.GetUI(activity));
        }
    }
}
```

so, on android the solution is in this method

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
```

and in this row fo code

```
activity?.StartActivity((Intent)auth.GetUI(activity));
```

My question is: How I can do the same in UWP, or how I can make it work in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all! I`ve found a solution for my purpose for UWP platform.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPageRenderer))]

namespace TestTask.UWP
{
    public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame _frame;
        private bool _isShown;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (_isShown) return;
            _isShown = true;

            if (Control == null)
            {
                WindowsPage windowsPage = new WindowsPage();

                var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                    clientId: "someID",
                    scope: "",
                    authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize"),
                    redirectUrl: new Uri("https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html"));

                _frame = windowsPage.Frame;
                if (_frame == null)
                {
                    _frame = new Frame();
                    //_frame.Language = global::Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

                    windowsPage.Content = _frame;
                    SetNativeControl(windowsPage);
                }

                auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {

                    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        AuthInfo.Token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                        AuthInfo.UserID = eventArgs.Account.Properties["user_id"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // The user cancelled
                    }
                };

                Type pageType = auth.GetUI();
                _frame.Navigate(pageType, auth);
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Please mark it solved!

Answer (score 0):

My question is: How I can do the same in UWP, or how I can make it work in UWP?

I'm not sure whether the [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth#xamarinauth) supports UWP or not, but for UWP, we can use [Web authentication broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker) for OAuth, you can check the official [WebAuthenticationBroker sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAuthenticationBroker), it's not xamarin, but you can code it in native UWP project and use Custom renderer to do the same thing in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Auth supports UWP for Standard/Traditional quite long.
Xamarin.Forms support was recently added and is not tested thoroughly (1.5.0-alpha)